# Wi-fi capture packets IVS.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, wifi

(^.^)"Hi again sorry for my English is not good if someone like correct my redaction I would appreciate this"

Hi, is anybody now if I can capture IVs with my iphone from the wi-fi networks , any source code, Api, tutorial, etc.. who can make this who can put the iphone wifi promiscuous mode monitor to capture packets.

I've looking for but can not find nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Stumbler](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler).

Note that **it uses private APIs** so most of this code is not suitable for
App Store aplications. But as a learning resource it's priceless.

Comment: (^.^)"Hi again sorry for my English is not good if someone like correct my redaction I would appreciate this"                                    Thanks @rokjarc but you now if there is another?  I try Stumbler but it dont run.

Comment: @NTTake: Hi! I only know of Stumbler. I will test it again in the afternoon and let you know (i'm not at Mac computer at the moment)

Comment: @NTTake: i guess you probably downloaded .zip file? you should download the source. For this you should install svn first. Then enter this command in terminal: svn checkout http://iphone-wireless.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ iphone-wireless-read-only

Comment: there's also a link for >= iOS5.0 It looks like you need to jailbrake newer iPhones. Anyway: you probably need this for private use? Since app like this would never pass App Store certification.

Comment: Hi @rokjarc sorry for the feedback backwardness i need this for privative use, for college workshop to capture IVs of network with security WEP, not need to App Store, and I have iPod touch 4 generation please helppp

Comment: If you need this for private use then the easiest way would be to try to compile stumbler source code. I think capturing raw packets is not yet implemented but you can still do that faster on stumbler base. Othervise you'd have to start everything from scratch.

Comment: Hi @rokjarc sorry for my dummy questions but how to get stumbler source code I download all the files of the [link](iphone-wireless.googlecode.com/svn/trunk) this is all the source code of Stumbler? And I don't undertand what you mean install svn first, please hellppppp do not leave me alone hahahaha thanks.. :)

Comment: You'll need SVN (subversion) client on your mac. I'm not sure, maybe it's installed by default. Go to console (terminal) and try to run command `svn checkout iphone-wireless.googlecode.com/svn/trunk iphone-wireless-read-only`. If you have svn installed this will download stumbler source to your computer, otherwise we're gonna have to figure out how to install svn. Sorry, it's been a few years since i installed svn so i forgot what i did :)

Comment: this link might help but i can't test it: http://www.rubyrobot.org/tutorial/subversion-with-mac-os-x

Comment: Ok, it's a progress :) Now this source will not work directly with xcode but it's a source so you can see how to start. I can try to modify this source into a xcode project but it'll take some time so i can't promise you when this would be available.

Comment: Thanks very much @rokjarc the SVN client was installed by default :), I download all the files and has three folders named: 1.Apple802111 2.CellStumber 3.Stumbler, The big headache is how can I use this in my project, how can I integrate this, is there any tutorial to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: I'll try to figure it out how to import this into an existing project - you should do the same :). It's gonna take some time.

Comment: Ok thanks this sounds good.. :) I will work on that thanks very much @rokjarc

Comment: Hi @rokjarc I could not understand how to integrate the code. I download this example source code but nothing works [link](http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/) :/     You could see something? thanks..

Comment: I only have iOS 4.3 device available at the moment. As i see you need a jailbroken device for this. I'll see if i can borrow one but can't make any promises.